# How to post HTTPS request using Retrofit?

Tags: android, https, retrofit

I build a restAdapter by this:

```
    return new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("https://www.xyz.com/")
            .build()
            .create(SafeUserApi.class);
```

then in the SafeUserApi.class (which is an interface) I have:

```
public interface SafeUserApi {
    @POST("/api/userlogin")
    void getUserLogin(@Body UserserLogin userLogin, Callback<LoginResult> cb);
}
```

But it does not work. Did I miss something?

I tried with Postman and it works. But in my device it doesn't.

I have these four library imported:

```
compile files('libs/okhttp-2.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/okhttp-urlconnection-2.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/okio-1.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/retrofit-1.8.0.jar')
```

Comment: How it doesnt work? Give the symptomps.

Comment: I solved it. I didnt include the keystore in my project. It takes me quite a while to gen the keystore. I used keystoreExplorer to gen the keystore, it is very easy wif that tool

Comment: I have the same problem and my retrofit request failure with error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Answer (score -7):

```
public interface SafeUserApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/userlogin")
    void getUserLogin(@Field("parm1")UserserLogin userLogin, Callback<LoginResult> cb);
}
```

Here parm1 is the POST parameter that you will be passing it to the server.
This will solve your problem

Comment: The question is mostly in using HTTPS protocol