# Android posting to https using retrofit

Tags: android, https, retrofit

I found similar post on [How to post HTTPS request using Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716001/how-to-post-https-request-using-retrofit) but it does't help me that much so i was wondering if some of you could help. This is my first post on SO and if you need any more information please let me know.

This is my code

```
public static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
    try {
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
            }
        } };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts,
                new java.security.SecureRandom());
        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext
                .getSocketFactory();

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .header("user-agent", "Android")
                        .header("Basic","apikey")
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
```

I know i can access https on my server with browser but when i try to do it here like

```
   public WebServiceCaller(OnServiceFinished listener) {
    final String baseUrl = "https://myserver.com/";
    this.listener=listener;

    final OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

    this.retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

    serviceCaller = retrofit.create(APIinterface.class);
}
```

then it can not finish the request. As soon as i move s from https it works. So i guess my question is why is it not working and how can i fix this?

this are my dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
```

Comment: Please include the fail/success logs from the okhttp client - you will need to add a debug interceptor that logs the traffic.

Comment: Can you check this: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1037

Comment: Maybe it's obvious, but I should ask: does your server have HTTPS enabled? If so, does it have a 3rd party certificate or is self signed? And if it's self signed, why not use https://letsencrypt.org/ certificates? Trusting all the certificates to be able to use a self signed certificate is (almost) like using HTTP in the first place (or worst, as it gives a false sense of security).

Comment: To dazza5000 I am having a hard time adding debug interceptor :(. Xavier i am not sure if i am answering this right but here it goes. I put my php script on a server that is not mine. This is all for my school project so false sense of security is not the issue. I can access my script through https when using browser but id does not work in code. I will now go and see letsencrypt.org

Comment: I have found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807237/protocolexception-expected-status-header-not-present